# Can I change the width of an image in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I set the width of an image in rails?

```
 <%= image_tag("full.png", :alt => "main") %>
```

Comment: Have you tried the doc ? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<%= image_tag("full.png", :alt=> "main", :size=>"100x200") %>
```

> **Note->>**  :size - Supplied as “{Width}x{Height}”, so “30x45” becomes width=“30”
>   and height=“45”. :size will be ignored if the value is not in the
>   correct format.

For full knowledge I refer you to see [AssetTagHelper](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) of `image_tag`